# perl - regex - get all text after string

Tags: regex, perl

Using Perl Regex how do I get the **IWantThisText** text block that comes after '**base64**' from the following:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset="KOI8-R"  
Content-Disposition: inline  
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64  

IWantThisTextIWantThisTextIWantThisTextIWantThisTextIWantThisTextIWantThisTex
tIWantThisTextIWantThisTextIWantThisTextIWantThisTextIWantThisTextIWantThisTe
xtIWantThisTextIWantThisTextIWantThisTextIWantThisTextIWantThisTextIWantThisT
extIWantThisTextIWantThisTextIWantThisTextIWantThisTextIWantThisTextIWantThis
TextIWantThisTextIWantThisTextIWantThisTextIWantThisTextIWantThisTextIWantThi
sTextIWantThi
```

EDIT:
What I have so far:

```
my ($textIWant) = $textblock =~ m/base64(.*?)/;
```

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: We need a bit more context.  For example, does anything follow that text?  Are spaces and newline characters valid characters?  Etc.  Right now this question is not specific enough.

Comment: I want everything and anything that comes after the 'base64' string

Comment: What is wrong with the code you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the whole of the file in variable `$textblock` then you can extract everything after the first occurrence of `base64` by removing the `?` non-greedy modifier from `(.*?)` and adding the `/s` modifier to your sample code.

The difference is that `.` normally matches anything *except* the newline character at the end of the string, so `(.*)` will stop at the end of the line containing `base64`. Adding `/s` changes it to match any character at all

```
my $text_i_want;
$text_i_want = $1 if $textblock =~ /base64(.*)/s;
```

will give you what you want, but note that it includes any space characters and the newline after `base64`

As an alternative, you can split the string into two at the first occurrence of `base64` and select the second part, like this

```
my $text_i_want = (split /base64/, $textblock, 2)[1];
```

which gives the same result

Answer (score 3):

You want the body of a MIME message. The body is separated from the header by a blank line. So, just check for two line breaks in a row.

```
my ($body) = $mime_message =~ /\n\r?\n(.*)/s;
```

That handles the standard CRLF line break used by MIME, but it also handles just LF too.